# How Connection Factory linked with Queue/Topic and JNDI in weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c

Please  give me idea how How Connection Factory linked with Queue/Topic  and  JNDI in weblogic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can probably be answered with a simple Google search

Comment: Hi, Ihavent  found any Link.  I know  the application connect to weblogic via Jndi and  Jndi look for the Queues or  topics. But In many cases Connection factory also used, what is the architecture of this flow. I need this basic idea. It will be  very help ful if  anyone can pink me the link